# Parse.com database and PHP

Tags: php, database, parse-platform

I come here to ask you something about queries and database management with the great website Parse.com.

I created a class directly on my App Manager on Parse.com with just one more column (in my case it's a pH level) and I created just one row to have a value to get back.

So as I said, after on my PHP code I don't now how to get back this pH value. I tried with `EqualTo` but I can't see how to use this function cause we've just one column. This is my code:

```
function getpH() {      
    $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
    if ($currentUser) {
        $query = new ParseQuery("figures");
        //$query->equalTo(???);
        $results = $query->find();
        return $results;
    } else {
        // show the signup or login page
        echo "pH non accesible"; 
    }
}
```

And I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Parse\ParseObject Object ( [serverData:protected] => Array (  [pH] => 10 ) [operationSet:protected] => Array ( ) [estimatedData:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array ( [pH] => 10 ) [dataAvailability:Parse\ParseObject:private] => Array (  [pH] => 1 ) [className:Parse\ParseObject:private] => figures [objectId:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 4JJxPPynTM [createdAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-07-20 10:36:20 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [updatedAt:Parse\ParseObject:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-07-20 14:41:45 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => Z ) [hasBeenFetched:Parse\ParseObject:private] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Your english is a lot better than most other peoples.

Comment: Check what methods are available for the ParseObject from their documentation

Comment: Already did, that's why I come here ..

Answer (score 0):

I did it alone ! Thanks !!

```
    function getpH() {      
    $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
    if ($currentUser) {
        $currentId = $currentUser->getObjectId();
        $query = new ParseQuery("swimming_pool_figures");
        $query->equalTo("user",$currentId);
        $results = $query->find();

        for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++){
            $object = $results[$i];
            }

            $pH = $object->get('pH');
            return $pH;
    } else {
        // show the signup or login page
        echo "pH non accesible"; 
    }
}
```